# Syntax error: bad input - Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
num = range(1,33)
num[0]=1
num[1]=2
for i in range(2,32):
    num[i]=num[i-1]+num[i-2]


total=0
for i in range(0,32):
    print num[i]
    if num[i]%2==0:
    total=total+num[i]
    else:
    num[i]=num[i+1]
```

I want to find the sum of the even numbers in the `num` array. Can anyone suggest what I did wrong here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indentation is very important in python

```
if num[i]%2==0:
total=total+num[i]
else:
num[i]=num[i+1]
```

should be

```
if num[i]%2==0:
    total=total+num[i]
else:
    num[i]=num[i+1]
```

Also, use consistent indentation e.g 4 spaces every where you have to introduce indentation.

Comment: wow, never knew this before. Thank you so much for pointing this out. I have used other languages before which really don't care about indentation.

Comment: very true. This is a good feature, which forces you to write readable, well indented code

Comment: @karthikr To a certain point... at which time it becomes a major pain in the ass :P

Comment: I would take this any day to what languages like php tend to become after a period of time :). @Ngenator

Comment: @karthikr I can find a lot more people that think of it as purely bad :)

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatively:**

```
total = sum([i for i in num if i % 2 == 0])
```

- [Sum( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) will return the summation of a list.
- `[i for i in num if i % 2 == 0]` is a [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

**For example:**

```
>> num = [1,2,3,4]
>> tmp = [i for i in num if i % 2 == 0]
>> print tmp
[2,4]

>> total = sum(tmp)
>> print total
6
```